# What is the maven dependency plugin for org.jfree.chart.labels?

Tags: maven, dependencies, jfreechart

I have added below two plugins in my pom but it is still failing -

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
<artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
<version>1.0.19</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>jfree</groupId>
<artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
<version>1.0.13</version>
</dependency>
```

But it still fails with, cannot find symbol-

**location: package org.jfree.chart.labels**

Comment: this are not plugin , this are dependency, please help us out with pom.xml, also add complete error log

Comment: One common mistake is to declare a `<dependency>` in the `<dependencyManagement>` section.

Comment: So where do I declare it?

Comment: Which is the undefined symbol? It seems you are adding two different dependencies for the same artifact. The groupId `jfree` is older one. You should use `org.jfree`. The latest version available is `1.5.0`. Add the dependencies in `<dependencies>` section.

Comment: I'll try to add this

Answer (score 0):

It should be defined inside "dependencies"

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>   

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jfree/jfreechart -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: I have defined it inside dependencies tag, since I have many other dependencies since I have only given this two dependency, but they are already under dependencies tag.